# How to create API to get students based on department Id

Tags: asp.net-core

I have created a api consisting of 4 models-students,contacts,department,batch
added controller to fetch all the 4 http verb methods -get,put,post,delete
[entire files[connection**your text**(https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrWwc.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsJLK.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZaPk.png)
now i need to create API to get students based on department Id.

i have added a controller named departController and given get method and get by id method.
i dont know where to write a query

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please post your dbcontext and the relationship about your student and department.